# Multivarate "RKHS" Examples

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples

I've been reading about RKHSs and Hilbert spaces of functions these days a bit these days and I haven't yet come across an example of a hilbert space $H$ whose elements are all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ for $n,m>1$ and for which the evaluation functions $E_x:f\mapsto f(x)$ are bounded.

Do such objects exist and if so what are some well-known examples?

The only thing I have at the moment is the space of $n\times m$ matrices with Frobenius norm...which is a bit underwhelming...

Comment: What is your _definition_ of a RKHS?  Because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) thinks a RKHS is a Hilbert space of real/complex-valued functions on a set.  So I don't know how one could consider functions to $\mathbb R^m$; nor do I see how matrices fit into this framework, unless we think of matrices as functions from $[n^2]$ to $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Oh for me its a hilbert space whose elements are functions (not to the base-field but to a topological vector space) and whose evaluation map is bounded linear operator

Comment: Do you have a reference for this sort of generalisation?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I guess any such space should be of the form $H\cong H' \otimes \mathbb{R}^m$ for some (classical) RKHS H'.

Comment: What about Sobolev spaces $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m)$ for $s > n/2$?  I thought this was kind of the canonical example.

Comment: Oh really?  I didn't know this worked when $m\neq 1$.  Do you happen to have a reference?  (I've only seen the recent paper of E. Novak ~ 2017)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would it not work?  Each coordinate function $f^{(i)}$ is $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and so it's continuous and its evaluation functions are bounded, and thus the evaluation functions for $f$ should likewise be bounded with a norm $\sqrt{m}$ times larger.

Comment: The standard spaces of entire functions (de Branges space, or just Paley-Wiener space) give you $m=n=2$, and for higher values, you can just take orthogonal sums of these and interpret them as functions on $\mathbb C^N$.